# Insert an image with a link in a PDF using PDFBox

Tags: pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have multiple PDFs and I want to insert a logo on every page which links to http://xyz.com (that is, clicking on the logo opens up xyz.com in the browser).
Also, I want to insert some text 'Click Here to view this page at xyz.com' next to the logo where 'Click Here' is a link (different link on every page, like http://xyz.com/show.php?id=76&page=3)

I have been able to add the logo and the text but could not figure out how to make the text a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had posted this on pdfbox-users mailing list also and a pointer to the solution was posted there by Hesham G. [Link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/201102.mbox/%3CD00779E1D63C4FF2BF565693C6C89BFF@your2f73f42422%3E)

Comment: Looks like the code was reorganized - the new link is http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/Annotation.java?view=markup

Comment: Both links are broken

Comment: Try this https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddAnnotations.java